# Embeding a generic google search with autocomplete - not a custom site search

Tags: google-search

Most people's home page is google.com.  My homepage is just a custom html page hosted on my computer.  I do this because I am a web developer, and I have several projects that I work on a one time, so I like to have quick links to all of them.  On that page I usually just have a Link to google.com for when I want to search.  But below all of my quick links, I want to add a google search box (with Autocompletions).  I first used a simple iframe to embed google.com into the page, but then my search results were confined to that iframe.  I wanted to search for something, then my results would open in a new tab.  I then came across this code snippet but it doesn't have Autocompletions:

http://www.refactory.org/s/google_search/view/2

How can I add Autocompletions to this?  Or is there a better way of doing it?  Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I ask because Google Custom Search (only answer at the moment) is more suited to only serach the site it's embeded on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Google Custom Search - here's the information about setting it up: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started

Once you have it set up you can choose 'Autocompletions' from the Control panel to turn on automatic or custom versions.